# How to download contents from url to a file in node js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a json content on a particular URL. I want to download that json content to a file say test.json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `node-fetch` module:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch('https://example.com/file.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        var destination = fs.createWriteStream('./destination-file.json');
        response.body.pipe(destination);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself,

I used the "packages" request and "fs"

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");

 request
 .get(theURLWithJson)
 .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  })
 .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullFilePathWithFileName));
```